# Lost JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I lost track of a certain JS or Jquery capability and no amount of research on my part seems to be able to find it.  Does anybody remember this --

There something like "execute" that allows JS or JQ to execute now, or in the future when the necessary elements or variables become available.

Any ideas???

Comment: I think term you want is `event delegation` that allows events to be bound for elements that don't exist yet. Not the same as executing code in the future though .. that would be a deeper topic. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes - delegate - I simply couldn't think of it and somehow going through lists of JS terms, I never found it.  Never mind about the "future code" - I  mis-stated the question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `.live` ([see here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) but that's deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and you should use event delegation via `.on` or plain JavaScript.

Example:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list')

list.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if(evt.target.tagName == 'LI') {
    alert('Clicked on the item that says: ' + evt.target.textContent)
  }
})

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var li = document.createElement('li')
  li.textContent = list.querySelectorAll('li').length
  list.appendChild(li)
})
```

Comment: `live()` is actually *completely gone* from 1.9 onwards, so you definitely should not use it.

Comment: Thank you.  "delegate" is what I was trying to remember.  Somehow despite going through a few lists of JS terms/functions etc., I never found it.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, jquery's on() which attaches event handlers to elements. The process is well know as event delegation.

http://api.jquery.com/on/